# How do I split a string at a space after a certain number of characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, web

So I have a nice long string that I need to split in Javascript at a space following a certain amount of characters. For instance, if I have

"You is a dog and I am a cat."

and I want it to split after 10 characters but at the next space... so rather than splitting dog up I want the next space to be the split point.

I hope I wrote that clearly, its a bit awkward to explain.

EDIT: I need to store all of this into an array. So splitting the string up as I described, but storing it into an array which I can iterate through. Sorry for the confusion- like I said, a bit odd to describe.

Comment: The answer you chose trimmed the spaces at the split points, but that does not appear to be part of your requirements.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider:

```
str = "How razorback-jumping frogs can level six piqued gymnasts!"
result = str.replace(/.{10}\S*\s+/g, "$&@").split(/\s+@/)
```

Result:

```
[
 "How razorback-jumping",
 "frogs can level",
 "six piqued",
 "gymnasts!"
]
```

Comment: Knowing the requirements better now, this is what I would have done or similar but I usually prefer `~` rather than `@` as token. Good stuff!

Comment: the best answer- thank you. and to everyone for their responses

Comment: But what happened to the spaces? Are they not part of the text? I don't see anything in the questions that says to trim the spaces?

Comment: @Xotic750: when we split a string by something, we're usually not interested in that "something". The question is essentially about wrapping a text - no need to preserve trailing spaces here.

Comment: I understand ´split´, but the OP also comments "but I need to store everything into an array, so I can't cut out anything.", to me that means lossless and I understand your assumption that it is not required. The problem is more to do with the unclear specification.

Comment: Can someone explain what exactly is going on here?  I looked up the first part and see it's a trim function, and seems to be using 10 as the trim amount but why is it .{10} and not {10}?  What is the S* for?  "$&@?"  I tried looking up some of these with no help, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @Lasagna: that's [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Thanks, I looked up the first part which seemed to be a sring trim, but I don't know waht the S* is for or the /\, I'll try to keep looking.

I also  see some of them like $& what's the @?  Also is there a way to take what you did here, and use a variable x instead of 10?  In my case the # is dependent on the size I am given.  For example if I have a 60px width rect I will need 10 as my x.  But if it's 30 I need 5 as my x.

Comment: @Lasagna: "@" here is just an arbitrary character I use as a marker. It doesn't have any special meaning in regex. If you need "10" to be a variable, you have to use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead of a literal.

Comment: So you can enter random characters and the regex will still work as intended?  So you just use them for yourself gotcha.

Thanks for this RegExp constructor, I will check it out, and hopefully it works :).

Comment: @Lasagna: exactly, I could have used `~` or `%` with the same effect - the main thing, it shouldn't appear elsewhere in the text.

Comment: Best answer. Thank you for saving my day!

Answer (score 11):

`.indexOf` has a `from` parameter.

```
str.indexOf(" ", 10);
```

You can get the string before and after the split, respectively, with:

```
str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" ", 10));
str.substring(str.indexOf(" ", 10));
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are after?
http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/j4kwL/

```
var s = "You is a dog and I am a cat.";
s = s.substring(10, s.length); // Cut out the first 10 characters.
s = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1, s.length); // look for the first space and return the
// remaining string starting with the index of the space.
alert(s);
```

To wrap it up, `String.prototype.indexOf` will return `-1` if the string you are looking for is not found. To make sure you don't get erroneous results, check for that before the last part. Also, the index of the space may be `string.length - 1`(the last character in the string is a space), in which case `s.index(" ") + 1` won't give you what you want.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I need to store everything into an array, so I can't cut out anything. its gonna be a regex thing most likely.

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want, and no regexs

```
var string = "You is a dog and I am a cat.",
    length = string.length,
    step = 10,
    array = [],
    i = 0,
    j;

while (i < length) {
    j = string.indexOf(" ", i + step);
    if (j === -1) {
        j = length;
    }

    array.push(string.slice(i, j));
    i = j;
}

console.log(array);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/5qgzZ/)

And here is a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/regexs-vs-while-indexof-and-step) comparing this answer and the regex answer that you chose.

Additional: if you want to trim the spaces from each block of text then change the code like so

```
array.push(string.slice(i, j).trim());
```

Comment: Looking fot this for several hours. Excellent !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex solution for some variety:

```
var result = [];
str.replace(/(.{10}\w+)\s(.+)/, function(_,a,b) { result.push(a,b); });

console.log(result); //=> ["You is a dog", "and I am a cat."]
```

Comment: nice, thank you sir. this is what I'm going for but I need to have an array of a much larger string. So if I have a 500 character string I want to have an array of the entire thing parsed like you have it here, but just applied to the entirety of the string.

Comment: @elclanrs You is a clever fellow but you should document your code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function breakAroundSpace(str) {
  var parts = [];
  for (var match; match = str.match(/^[\s\S]{1,10}\S*/);) {
    var prefix = match[0];
    parts.push(prefix);
    // Strip leading space.
    str = str.substring(prefix.length).replace(/^\s+/, '');
  }
  if (str) { parts.push(str); }
  return parts;
}

var str = "You is a dog and I am a cat and she is a giraffe in disguise.";
alert(JSON.stringify(breakAroundSpace(str)));
```

produces

```
["You is a dog",
 "and I am a",
 "cat and she",
 "is a giraffe",
 "in disguise."]
```