# Split string after approx 100 chars and next sign (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I would like to split a string after approx. 200 chars or the next special sign:

The string is formatted like `<data>|...|<data>|`, where one `<data>`block is between 30 and 70 chars.

My desired result would be a String array like

```
<data>|<data>|
<data>|
<data>|<data>|<data>|
```

where every line is approx 200 chars long.

My code looks like

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RegexpTest {

@Test
public void testRegexp() throws Exception {
    String data = "Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|";
    String pat = ".{1,200}(\\d|\\s|\\w|\\.|\\:{1,70})\\|";
    String ans = data.replaceAll(pat, "X");
    //Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pat);
    //Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(str);

    System.out.println(data.length()); //prints 528
    System.out.println(ans.length()); //prints 3
}
}
```

The result produces a correct amount of replacements (3) but the overall result  should be a String array.

Is there a regexp (similar to [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246031/how-do-i-split-a-string-at-a-space-after-a-certain-number-of-characters-in-javas)) that could handle this problem? A solution with for loops is also acceptable.

**Scratch Pad**:

Feel free to test on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yZ2jP3/1) (includes my attempt and the test data)

Comment: I get an error with your code in the first println: `str` is not defined.

Comment: Why don't you split it one every special charachter and then reconstruct it. Slower, but easier to do.

Comment: @Sotix: `str` is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without regex. Just split the data at the "|". Then check if adding a part to the existing line will exceed the 200 characters. If it does then start a new line. Quick and dirty:

edit: added comments and formatting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your data
    String data = "Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|Symbol Ticker:1466654463000:157.71:TRADE:42|";
    // do the split
    List<String> out = new Test().splitToApproxAt(data, 200);
    // print the splitted lines
    for(String o : out){
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}

public List<String> splitToApproxAt(String data, int len){
    // split at the pipe symbol "|"
    String[] parts = data.split("\\|");

    // this will be our current line in progress
    String line = "";

    // this will store the lines up to 200 chars
    List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

    // for every data-part
    for( String part : parts ){
        if(part.length() > len){
            System.out.println("oh shit, what do?");
            continue;
        }
        // would this exceed the 200 chars?
        if( line.length() + part.length() > len){
            // yes! add previous line to output
            // and start a new one.
            out.add(line);
            line = part;
        }else{
            // no we can attach that to the
            // current line
            if(line.length()>0){
                // delimit with pipe
                line += "|" +part;
            }else{
                // line was empty, no pipe
                line = part;
            }
        }
    }
    // add the last line to the output
    out.add(line);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: You are right, to quantify things: to minimize the errors and cover boundary cases like 200 chars of data, a regex split will not do, one must follow your approach more or less.