# How do I split a sentence to an array of sentences with maximum number of characters without cutting words?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have this string:

> This is a sentence to be split by the code, how can I make it smaller with maximum number of 30 characters?

And I want to make it into this array in Javascript:

```
[
"This is a sentence to be split",
"by the code, how can I make",
"it smaller with maximum",
"number of 30 characters?"
]
```

How can I split that string, using Javascript, with maximum lenght of 30 characters per each sentence split, and with whole words?

I found this code:

[How do I split a string at a space after a certain number of characters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246031/how-do-i-split-a-string-at-a-space-after-a-certain-number-of-characters-in-javas)

That did a great job, but it found the space after the 30 characters limit, not before it:

```
function myFunction() {
    str = "This is a sentence to be split by the code, how can I make it smaller with maximum number of 30 characters?"
    result = str.replace(/.{30}\S*\s+/g, "$&@")
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: `/.{0,30}\s+/g` or `/(.{0,30})\s+/g`

Comment: Hello, if I try it on this string:
"This is a sentence to be splitted by the code"
It gives this answer:
This is a sentence to be,
splitted by the,
code

Which is not correct.

Is there another way?

Comment: And what is correct?

Comment: what i want is every 30 characters in one part and if the 30th characters is in the middle of a word i want it to go back to the last space like "This is a sentence to be split,....... every part to be 30 characters

Comment: Exactly, `s=s.replace(/(.{0,30})\s/g, "$1\n")`, see [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/DO2E5V/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid a space at the beginning or at the end of each part, use:

```js
var str = "This is a sentence to be split by the code, how can I make it smaller with maximum number of 30 characters?";
console.log(str.match(/\S.{0,29}(?=\s+|$)/g));
```