# How can I split a string in JavaScript after the first space after 15 characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read the solution on this post [How do I split a string at a space after a certain number of characters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246031/how-do-i-split-a-string-at-a-space-after-a-certain-number-of-characters-in-javas)

And it works to a certain point. But what I am trying to achieve is slightly different.

I have a user input which has a 40 character limit. I am taking that input and displaying it on the screen. However, I need to split the input at around 20 characters and then insert the remainder on the next line. And it is only allowed to go on 2 lines max.

UPDATE:: I should also mention here that as well as displaying the text on the front end, we also need to pass the string to our backend. But instead of sending it with the `<br/>`, we need to insert `\n` to force the new line in our backend system.

Ultimately, each line cannot be over 20 characters. However, it needs to be dynamic, so that if the user inputs a string that is 30 characters, but the space comes before the 20th character, how can I adjust it so that it splits at a space before the 20th character? - I hope that makes sense.

For example

> TEXT12345 STRING46789

Should appear like this

> TEXT12345
>
> STRING46789

but, also the following

> TEXT STRING ABCDEF
>
> NEW LINE HERE

Each line needs to be a maximum of 20 characters and I can't force hyphenation.

The below code is what I have done, but it doesn't work well as I often get 'undefined' before the space. Plus, its not dynamically looking for a space before the 20 character limit

```
Child1Name.keyup(function(e) {

    var stringValue = Child1Name.val();

    if (stringValue.length > 19) {

      let [firstLine, secondLine] = stringValue.replace(/.{20}\S*\s+/g, "$&@").split(/\s+@/)
      
      previewChild1Name.html(firstLine + "<br/>" + secondLine);
      
    }else{

      previewChild1Name.text(stringValue);
      
    }

});
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just to be sure.. are you trying to do word wrap by yourself? I ask just because I see in your code that in the end you are going to set the html or text of a given element. Wouldn't it better dealing with it using css? I hope my comment didn't go too much off topic

Comment: Hi @DiegoDeVita thanks for your comment. I could probably achieve the front end part of this in CSS. However, I should have also mentioned, that this needs to be also sent to our backend as a string with `\n` in place of the `<br/>` so that when its sent to the backend system it forces the new line

Comment: ok then just ignore my comment.. I asked just to be perfectly sure that you already considered that option. By the way there were no need of newline nor br in the content of an element if you needed to show its content with word wrap. But as you said you need a way to know in absolute terms how your content splits on different lines and that's fair enough so that not only the GUI holds how

Comment: The fourth answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript) seems to be answering your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function like below. First split your string with space and loop over it to append the word. If after appending a new word it surpasses the length then add existing word to arr and clear the current string.

Try the code below.

```js
function getSplittedString(s, length) {
  let arr = [];
  let str = '';
  s.split(' ').forEach(x => {
    if (str !== '' && (str + ' ' + x).length > length) {
      arr.push(str);
      str = '';
    }
    str = (str + ' ' + x).trim();
  });

  if (str !== '') {
    arr.push(str);
  }

  return arr.join('<br/>')
}

console.log(getSplittedString('TEXT12345 STRING46789', 20));
```

Comment: Hi @Karan, that's worked perfectly, many thanks. I was just thinking that I should use a loop to somehow count the length and then you posted this. Amazing, many thanks

Answer (score -1):

from what i have seen and found on this site:
[mdn website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?retiredLocale=en)

You can use split(on strings) like this on stringvalue(should be the entire string);

```
var stringvalue = 'TEXT12345 STRING46789';

var words = str.split(' '); // what charater need to cut the string
console.log(words[0]);
// expected output: "TEXT12345"
```

Sorry for the rushing the answer, kinda busy rn Hope this helps.